# F# "for loop" optimization

Tags: optimization, f#, for-loop

Code example:

```
let foo1 (arr : int[]) = 
    for i = 0 to arr.Length-1 do
        arr.[i] <- i

let foo2 (arr : int[]) = 
    for i in [0..arr.Length-1] do
        arr.[i] <- i
```

I thought that this functions should be equivalent to each other (in terms of performance). But if we look into IL listing, we'll see:

First function, 15 lines, no dynamic allocations, no `try` operator, no virtual calling:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: br.s IL_0011
// loop start (head: IL_0011)
    IL_0005: ldarg.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_000d: ldloc.0
    IL_000e: ldc.i4.1
    IL_000f: add
    IL_0010: stloc.0

    IL_0011: ldloc.0
    IL_0012: ldarg.0
    IL_0013: ldlen
    IL_0014: conv.i4
    IL_0015: blt.s IL_0005
// end loop

IL_0017: ret
```

and second one - almost 100 lines, lots of allocations/deallocations, callings of virtual functions, lots of `try`/`Dispose`:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
IL_0002: ldc.i4.1
IL_0003: ldarg.0
IL_0004: ldlen
IL_0005: conv.i4
IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
IL_0007: sub
IL_0008: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators/OperatorIntrinsics::RangeInt32(int32, int32, int32)
IL_000d: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators::CreateSequence<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
IL_0012: call class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<!!0> [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule::ToList<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
IL_0017: stloc.0
IL_0018: ldloc.0
IL_0019: unbox.any class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>
IL_001e: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
IL_0023: stloc.1
.try
{
    // loop start (head: IL_0024)
        IL_0024: ldloc.1
        IL_0025: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
        IL_002a: brfalse.s IL_003e

        IL_002c: ldloc.1
        IL_002d: callvirt instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
        IL_0032: stloc.3
        IL_0033: ldarg.0
        IL_0034: ldloc.3
        IL_0035: ldloc.3
        IL_0036: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Int32
        IL_003b: nop
        IL_003c: br.s IL_0024
    // end loop

    IL_003e: ldnull
    IL_003f: stloc.2
    IL_0040: leave.s IL_005b
} // end .try
finally
{
    IL_0042: ldloc.1
    IL_0043: isinst [mscorlib]System.IDisposable
    IL_0048: stloc.s 4
    IL_004a: ldloc.s 4
    IL_004c: brfalse.s IL_0058

    IL_004e: ldloc.s 4
    IL_0050: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0055: ldnull
    IL_0056: pop
    IL_0057: endfinally

    IL_0058: ldnull
    IL_0059: pop
    IL_005a: endfinally
} // end handler

IL_005b: ldloc.2
IL_005c: pop
IL_005d: ret
```

My question is why does F# compiler uses so complicated code for `foo2`? Why does it use an `IEnumerable` to implement so trivial loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the 2nd example if you use range expression, it will be converted into normal `for` loop:

```
let foo2 (arr : int[]) = 
    for i in 0..arr.Length-1 do
        arr.[i] <- i
```

and become equivalent to `foo1`.

I quote [Section 6.3.12 Range Expressions in F# language specs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997065):

> A sequence iteration expression of the form for var in expr1 .. expr2
>   do expr3 done is sometimes elaborated as a simple for loop-expression
>   (§6.5.7).

However, your 2nd example is more like:

```
let foo2 (arr : int[]) = 
    let xs = [0..arr.Length-1] (* A new list is created *)
    for i in xs do
        arr.[i] <- i
```

where you have created a new list explicitly.

Comment: I didn't know about this `for i in 0..arr.Length-1 do` expression. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

What your seeing is the standard difference between using an index based enumeration and an `IEnumerable` based enumeration (or in C# terms `for` vs `foreach`).

In the second sample the expression `[0..arr.Length-1]` is creating a collection and F# is using `IEnumerable<T>` to enumerate the values.  Part of this enumeration style involves the use of `IEnumerator<T>` which implements `IDisposable`.  The `try / finally` block you are seeing is generated to ensure that the `IDisposable::Dispose` method is called at the end of the enumeration even in the face of an exception.

Could F# optimize the second example into the first and avoid all of the extra overhead?  It's possible that they could do this optimization.  Essentially peek through the range expression, not it's just a simple numeric range and hence generate the equivalent `for` code.

Should F# optimize the second example. My vote would be no. Features like this often look trivial from the outside but actually implementing them, and more importantly maintaining them, can be rather expensive.  An astute user could always convert their code back to the standard `for` version and avoid the `IEnumerable<T>` overhead (should the profiler reveal it to be an issue).  Not implementing the optimization frees up the F# team to implement other awesome features.

Comment: I will add to this comment, that using a list rather than an iterater is considered more 'safe' since an iterator is mutable and a list in F# consist of immutable values, so no side effects.